# Plotly figure not showing with IPython

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, ipython, plotly-express

I'm trying out plotly express by pasting the [official example](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) in an `IPython` console.

requirements.txt

```
ipython
plotly
pandas
```

Run the below

```py
import plotly.express as px

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import IPython; IPython.embed(using=False)
```

Paste this:

```
In [1]:     df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
   ...:     fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
   ...:     fig.show()
   ...: 

In [2]:
```

Nothing happens. It works fine (a browser page opens up) if I just run the whole thing as a script without `IPython`. However during development I would rather be able to play around.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

(Posted this question also on their [community page](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-not-working-with-ipython/62629))

Comment: what version of plotly and jupyter / jupyter lab are you using?  as of plotly 5.0 jupyter integration has been significantly improved https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/releases/tag/v5.0.0

Comment: Open the notebook in the browser directly : start the server from the command line `jupyter notebook` and it should be fine (`NotebookApp.open_browser` is True  by default).

Comment: @RobRaymond @EricLavault I am not using Jupyter. I'm simply using IPython; `ipython==8.1` and `plotly==5.6.0`

Comment: Mmm.. maybe you should. IPython is used as a Python shell and kernel for Jupyter (kernel is maintained by the Jupyter team) but the notebook interface and other language-agnostic parts of IPython has been moved under the Jupyter name, which refers the supported language Julia, Python, and R. This is not a big deal to `pip3 install jupyter`.

Comment: @EricLavault it does work though with just `plotly` and `pandas` installed (just tested in a virtual env) so this feels like a bug

Comment: I got the same behaviour if I try via `IPython.embed`, it seems like it cannot open the browser, or maybe it just need some additional parameter..

Comment: I went with `bokeh` in the end. Works out of the box as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked here?
https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/

I'm having a similar issue where if I launch Jupyter Notebook from a virtual environment called my_env with conda: `conda activate my_env` and then `jupyter notebook`, then `fig.show()` won't show anything. Following their troubleshooting page, I found that `fig.show('notebook')` will show the figure using IPython. I hope that link will help you find the problem!